# Android SDK: Наложение изображения на видео во время съемки

Tags: android, android-sdk

Подскажите пожалуйста, как проще всего организовать запись видео с наложением изображения на подобии watermark на каждый кадр видео?

Видится 2 варианта:

1. Наложение кадр за кадром, но реально ли с Camera2 API такое провернуть?
2. Пост обработка. На 1080p процесс сильно затянется даже для 10 минутного видео.